# PHP move uploaded files to random folder

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

The following code simply uploads two files. I want to put both files in a unique folder. The code does create a random folder, however, how can I move the uploaded files into that folder?

**`.php`**

```
<?php

    $new_image_name = uniqid("IMG_",false);

    $target_dir = uniqid();
    mkdir("C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/" . $target_dir);

    //I just put random_dir here as a placeholder   
    $target_file = $random_dir . $new_image_name . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $target_file2 = $random_dir . $new_image_name . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["name"]);


    if ( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] ) move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],  $target_file);
    if ( $_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["tmp_name"] ) move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2);

?>
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), the second parameter should be the destination, in your case `$target_file` and `$target_file2`, which doesn't contains the `$target_dir`...

Comment: Yes exactly! The variable `$random_dir` (in `$target_file`) should be the newly generated unique directory. But how do I pass this new directory  to `$random_dir`?

Comment: Well, you could do `$target_dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/" . $target_dir;`, and then `mkdir($target_dir);`, and in `$target_file = $target_dir . $new_image_name . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);`, right?

Comment: Thank for the suggestion! However, unfortunately, now the files get moved to `/uploads`, and not to the unique directory.

Comment: I don't know how it works exactly on Windows (I am using Linux servers), but I guess you are missing some `/` from `$target_file`. `var_dump($target_file);` and check the result, and go from there.

Comment: alright will do, thanks.